# Set value to a referenced JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, reference, variable-assignment, javascript-objects

For example, I have the following JS object:

```
var obj = {
    n: 0,
    o: {}
};

var nGlobal = obj.n;
var oGlobal = obj.o;
```

And want to use global variables in order to make it look like this:

```
var obj = {
    n: 5,
    o: {
        x: 7
    }
};
```

Obviously, I am able to assign a value to a property of `oGlobal`:

```
oGlobal.x = 7;
```

However, is there any way to change the value of `obj.n` through `nGlobal`, without mentioning `obj`?
Just something like this:

```
console.log(obj); // {n: 1, o: {}}

nGlobal.set(5);
// or
nGlobal.value = 5;

console.log(obj); // {n: 5, o: {}}
```

Comment: JavaScript is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference. Assigning a value to a variable never changes the value of another variable or property (exception: global scope and `with`).

Comment: @FelixKling Or rather, for primitives: pass-by-value and non-primitives: pass-by-reference

Comment: @Tushar: No, objects are represented **as** references, but that has nothing to do with **pass-by**-reference. Pass-by-reference and pass-by-value refers to how variables and parameters related to each other. It has nothing to do with the values they hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

> No, there is not.

Long answer:

> 1. In JS primitive types are immutable and passed by values.
> 2. JS implements pass-by-value strategy, which means that ALL data is always passed by value (in case if you pass a reference to object - the reference is passed by value)

One important consequence from the items above: in JS there is no way to change the original object using the `=` operation. That is: you can modify an object when you have a reference to it, but you cannot swap one object with something else so that all other references also "were modified".

Related:

- [Evaluation strategy - Call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)

Credits:

- [<sub>Felix Kling</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)

Comment: I know what you mean, but I think still think this should not be conflated. For example your answer could be interpreted that if `obj.n` was an object, `nGlobal = someNewObject` would magically work (but of course it does not). I guess what's more important here is that primitive values are immutable.

Comment: @FelixKling second attempt